# How to remove original shape with pyglet when changing position

Tags: python, pyglet

Just learning to use pyglet for some graphics, i have a grid in the image below. The "player" is a circle. When i change the x positon of the circle:

```
circle.x = new x
cirle.draw()
```

This works to render the second circle as you can see, but how do i now remove the original circle? It doesn't update the actual initial object it seems.

[image]

Comment: `circle.draw()` will draw a new circle everytime you call it, you need to clear the screen before drawing anything at new position. `window.clear()`

Comment: @K450 so the entire grid needs to be redrawn as well then?

Comment: yes, to make it a little easier and efficient there is something called batch rendering. You should use that.

Comment: @K450 i've seen that thanks just not tried it out yet, but i will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redraw the entire scene in every frame. Clear the window with [`clear`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.Window.clear). e.g.:

```py
window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    # draw board
    # [...]

    cirle.draw()
```